# Split python list of booleans

Tags: python

I have a list

```
[True, False, False, True, True]
```

I need to receive

```
[[True],[True, True]]
```

Pleace help me with ideas how to do this 'pythonicly'.
Thank you

Comment: Define your constraints for when `[True]` vs `[True, True]` should happen.

Comment: Please share what you have tried. SO is not a code writing service but a place where you share what you have tried and we help correct it

Comment: I try to count sum of True-groups...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to accomplish this. Essentially it will group consecutive runs of `True` and `False` respectively, then just keep the groups of `True` using a list comprehension.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> values = [True, False, False, True, True]
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(values) if k]
[[True], [True, True]]
```

Comment: dang beat me to it

Comment: Thanks! This solution has helped me to solve my issue.